# Prime Factorization With Typos

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

It is well known that multiplying two large primes to get their product is easy, and factoring the result to get the prime factors is hard, such that if someone has published a large number and says it's the product of two primes, and then tells you the two factors, this is fairly conclusive evidence that they are the one who originated the product.

However, consider a slightly modified problem: The person presenting you with the two prime factors doesn't have to have their product *equal* the pre-existing number; they only need to generate a result which is *nearly* correct, as if the published number had a typo in it. It must otherwise appear to be a standard private-key claim, such that if the 'typo' was corrected it would be the standard known-difficult problem and therefore a strong proof of being the original author.

To specify this formally, say that the product of the two large primes they present must have edit distance one to the published number. (Of the well-known edit distance metrics, the most natural would be [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), which allows insertion, deletion, substitution, and transposition of adjacent characters, though the context where this came to my attention was actually considering solely transposition of adjacent digits.)

How difficult is this problem? I am interested in the answers for considering the two numbers as strings in base 10 and in base 2, and of course a generalization for arbitrary bases would be even more interesting.

Comment: If the two factors don't have to be primes, then the problem is easy: just set the last digit to 5, and your factors are $5,n/5$. (Where $n$ is the number with a typo in it.)

Comment: If the two factors do have to be prime, there should be a quick method "most of the time". We'll adjust the digits such that there's a small prime (eg. $p<1000$) we can divide out, and hope that we get lucky and the remaining number is prime. If the number has $k$ digits, then there are $9k$ modifications to those digits. A given modification has about an 80% chance of being divisible by a small non-2,5 prime, so we win if any of about $7k$ numbers of similar size to $n$ are prime. Prime frequency is about $1/k\log10$. So $P(win) = 1-(1-1/k\log 10)^{7k} \approx 1 - \exp(-7/\log 10)=0.952...$

Comment: A one digit insertion can easily make a number a multiple of $3$, $9$, or $11$...

Comment: The two presented numbers have to be large primes - otherwise it's not a credible fake. Factoring the product of 11 and a large prime is easy, and factoring the product of a prime less than 1000 and a second prime is not _easy_ but is not a strong demonstration of owning the signature.